# ENABLE form caching in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, caching

I am going a little crazy here trying to find a solution to something that is probably pretty straight forward.

I have a group of reports on an intranet (not accesible to the outside world) and each report has an input form that has a bunch of HTML inputs that vary the report data.

Problem being when you hit back to the form from the report the form is reset to it's original state.  I want it to cache (remember the HTML input variables) and all I can find is how to turn caching off, I want it on!  I would prefer not to do this with $_SESSION and $_COOKIE storing as I have 120 reports with roughly 10 or so inputs each, so its going to take forever to store everyone of them and re-load variables on refresh.

I am not the server administrator, but I beleive we are running Apache 2.2 web server.  These are all PHP/HTML based pages.  Any advice would be great!

It is not to do with my Browser as other forms are being cached.  I am more looking into what modules on the server need to be activated to allow caching and what notes I should put in the header of the forms to allow caching.  The intranet runs through a proxy so I am thinking I will need cache-control to be public.

EDIT:

When I run the form page, the HTTP headers show me this which I feel should be changed:

(under Response Headers)

```
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
 Via: *[REMOVED]*
 Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
 Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
 Pragma: no-cache
 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
 Date: Wed, 13 Feb 2013 23:33:32 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 Content-Length: 5191
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

I have a feeling I need to change the Cache-Control and Pragma values.  Anyone know how to acheive this?

Comment: This is browser related issue. It is up to the browser, if it remembers the data that were in the inputs or not.

Comment: hmmm... Why does my browser cache data from an old site and not from the new one?

Comment: It may be, that the web page explicitly forces the browser not to use that data. Easy example is setting `input.value=""` by javasript, but there may be some headers sent too (I don't know about any though).

Comment: I authored all the pages.  Nothing of this nature exists.  The pages run from the old server that store the form data don't appear to have any different headers so am thinking that mod_caching or something like that is switched off on the Apache server

Comment: And what about removing this? `Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT`

Comment: Would be nice... how do I modify the header info?  As a side note, from what I have reaad expires will only be looked at if Pragma value is either public, private or cache... again need to know how to change these headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

trying adding these headers to the top of the page:

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime("+2 day")));
```

NOTE: if the form submits and post data to a second page, you may want to put it at the top of both pages. also, make sure the code is after any session_start(); if you are using sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the autocomplete attribute of the inputs to on.

```
<input name="myinput" autocomplete="on" type="text">
```

Comment: Autocomplete doesn't work for checboxes, radio boxes, select boxes etc.  There is next to no text fields for autocomplete to be useful unfortunately.